# Swift 3 iMessage Extension doesn't open URL

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imessage, ios-messages-extension

I am creating an iOS Application iMessage Extension.

According to [Example by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html), I creating a message according to provided logic

```
guard let url: URL = URL(string: "http://www.google.com") else { return }

let message = composeMessage(url: url)
activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: { [weak self] (error: Error?) in
    guard let error = error else { return }
    self?.presentAlert(error: error)        
})
```

also

```
private func composeMessage(url: URL) -> MSMessage {
    let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
    layout.caption = "caption"
    layout.subcaption = "subcaption"
    layout.trailingSubcaption = "trailing subcaption"

    let message = MSMessage()
    message.url = url
    message.layout = layout

    return message
}
```

and

```
private func presentAlert(error: Error) {
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "Error",
        message: error.localizedDescription,
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: .cancel,
        handler: nil
    )

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(
        alertController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

As far as I understand, after message is sent, on a click, Safari browser should be opened.

When I click on a sent message, `MessageViewController` screen takes place in whole screen, without opening safari or another app.

Where is the problem? How can I achieve desired functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I use to open a URL from a iMessage extension. It is currently working to open the Music app in the WATUU iMessage application. For instance with the URL
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/as%C3%AD/1154300311?i=1154300401&uo=4&app=music"

This functionality currently works in iOS 10, 11 and 12

```
func openInMessagingURL(urlString: String){
    if let url = NSURL(string:urlString){
        let context = NSExtensionContext()
        context.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
        var responder = self as UIResponder?

        while (responder != nil){
            if responder?.responds(to: Selector("openURL:")) == true{
                responder?.perform(Selector("openURL:"), with: url)
            }
            responder = responder!.next
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4**

```
func openInMessagingURL(urlString: String){
    if let url = URL(string:urlString){
        let context = NSExtensionContext()
        context.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
        var responder = self as UIResponder?

        while (responder != nil){
            if responder?.responds(to: #selector(UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:))) == true{
                responder?.perform(#selector(UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:)), with: url)
            }
            responder = responder!.next
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I think you will find that the context.open can be removed as it's not doing anything. The code which walks up the tree to find who responds to openURL is what works.

Comment: Posted an answer below, thanks, updated for current iOS and Swift 4, using your technique

Answer (score 2):

I think safari Browser only opens for macOS. This worked for me:

```
override func didSelectMessage(message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {

        if let message = conversation.selectedMessage {
            // message selected

            // Eg. open your app:
            let url = // your apps url
            self.extensionContext?.openURL(url, completionHandler: { (success: Bool) in

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried calling `extensionContext?.openURL(url, completionHandler:nil)` without any success. At least in iOS 10.

Comment: i am using this code block to open my deep link url but it not working         self.extensionContext?.open(url as URL, completionHandler:{
                (success: Bool) in
            
        })

Answer (score 2):

Using the technique shown by [Julio Bailon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104356/53870)

Fixed for Swift 4 and that `openURL` has been deprecated.

Note that the `extensionContext?.openURL` technique does **not** work from an iMessage extension - it only opens your current app.

I have posted a full sample app showing the technique on [GitHub](https://github.com/AndyDentFree/im-plausibilities/tree/master/webFromIM) with the relevant snippet here:

```
    let handler = { (success:Bool) -> () in
        if success {
            os_log("Finished opening URL")
        } else {
            os_log("Failed to open URL")
        }
    }

    let openSel = #selector(UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:))
    while (responder != nil){
        if responder?.responds(to: openSel ) == true{
            // cannot package up multiple args to openSel so we explicitly call it on the iMessage application instance
            // found by iterating up the chain
            (responder as? UIApplication)?.open(url, completionHandler:handler)  // perform(openSel, with: url)
            return
        }
        responder = responder!.next
    }
```

Comment: Look at the sample app I linked to and see where it is in that code. It's too hard to explain out of context. Those samples are carefully crafted to demonstrate just one main point per sample.

https://github.com/AndyDentFree/im-plausibilities/tree/master/webFromIM

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Xcode 11. Getting the error "'open(_:options:completionHandler:)' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS"

Comment: I noticed that too - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153341/xcode11-error-open-optionscompletionhandler-is-unavailable-in-application

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not possible to open an app from a Message Extension, except the companion app contained in the Workspace. We have tried to open Safari from our Message Extension, it did not work, this limitation seems by design.

You could try other scenari to solve your problem :

1. *Webview in Expanded Message Extension*

   You could have a Webview in your Message Extension, and when you click
   on a message, you could open the Expanded mode and open you Url in the
   Webview.

The user won't be in Safari, but the page will be embedded in your Message Extension.

2. *Open the Url in the Companion App*

   On a click on the message, you could open your Companion app (through
   the Url Scheme with MyApp://?myParam=myValue) with a special parameter
   ; the Companion app should react to this parameter and could redirect
   to Safari through OpenUrl.

In this case, you'll several redirects before the WebPage, but it should allow to go back to the conversation.

We have also found that we could instance a SKStoreProductViewController in a Message Extension, if you want to open the Apple Store right in Messages and let the user buy items.

Comment: It is possible. Please check the following answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to insert a link, then you should use `activeConversation.insertText` and insert the link. Touching the message will open `Safari`.

Answer (score -1):

1. openURL in didSelectMessage:conversation: by using extensionContext
2. handle the URL scheme in your host AppDelegate

Comment: inherited method `didSelectMessage:conversation:` is not called when the desired message is tapped. It is triggered, when message is selected before being sent. What is more, handling URL scheme in host app delegate is even worse, host app might haven't be even launched, despite the fact, that is in a background as a best case scenario...

Comment: @DaumantasVersockas When you tap sent message, you should handle it on didBecomeActiveWithConversation: method, you can get selectedMessage from Conversion. Using extensionContext openURL will launch your host app.