# ios 11 imessage extension message.url does not open safari

Tags: ios, swift, safari, imessage-extension

I'm adding an `iMessage extension` target to my app. The extension is supposed to send a message that has a `url` attribute. The behaviour I'm expecting when a user touches the message is to open the browser using the `url` attribute of the message.

I have a button in my `messageView` which executes this code:

```
@IBAction func labelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.imageTitle = "iMessage Extension"
        layout.caption = "Hello world!"
        layout.subcaption = "Test sub"
        guard let url: URL = URL(string: "https://google.com") else { return }

        let message = MSMessage()
        message.layout = layout
        message.summaryText = "Sent Hello World message"
        message.url = url

        activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

If I touch the message, it expands the `MessageViewController`

I have then added this:

```
override func didSelect(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {

        if let message = conversation.selectedMessage {
            // message selected

            // Eg. open your app:
            self.extensionContext?.open(message.url!, completionHandler: nil)
        }
}
```

And now, when I touch the message, it opens my main app but still not my browser.

I have seen on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351549/swift-3-imessage-extension-doesnt-open-url) (where I cannot comment, thus I opened this post) that it is impossible to open in `Safari` but I have a [news app](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/igeneration/id346175650?mt=8) which inserts links to articles and allows with a click on the message to open the article in a browser window, while the app is installed.

So, can someone please tell how I can proceed to force opening the link in a browser window?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use an `SFSafariViewController`. As the other post point out you cannot kick users out to Safari from a messages extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have considered the answer in the other post  if I did not have this news app that opens a window in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick to insert a link in a message. It does not allow to create an object that has an url attribute but just to insert a link directly which will open in the default web browser.

```
activeConversation?.insertText("https://google.com", completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have published a [sample on github](https://github.com/AndyDentFree/im-plausibilities/tree/master/webFromIM) showing how to launch a URL from inside an iMessage extension. It just uses a fixed URL but the launching code is what you need.

Copying from my [readme](https://github.com/AndyDentFree/im-plausibilities/edit/master/webFromIM/README.md)

The obvious thing to try is `self.extensionContext.open` which is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1416791-open) as *Asks the system to open a URL on behalf of the currently running app extension.*

That doesn't work. However, you can iterate back up the responder chain to find a suitable handler for the open method (actually the iMessage instance) and invoke `open` with that object.

This approach works for URLs which will open a local app, like settings for a camera, or for web URLs.

The main [code](https://github.com/AndyDentFree/im-plausibilities/blob/master/webFromIM/webFromIM%20MessagesExtension/MessagesViewController.swift#L100)

```
@IBAction public func onOpenWeb(_ sender: UIButton)  {
    guard let url = testUrl else {return}

    // technique that works rather than self.extensionContext.open
    var responder = self as UIResponder?
    let handler = { (success:Bool) -> () in
        if success {
            os_log("Finished opening URL")
        } else {
            os_log("Failed to open URL")
        }
    }

    let openSel = #selector(UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:))
    while (responder != nil){
        if responder?.responds(to: openSel ) == true{
            // cannot package up multiple args to openSel so we explicitly call it on the iMessage application instance
            // found by iterating up the chain
            (responder as? UIApplication)?.open(url, completionHandler:handler)  // perform(openSel, with: url)
            return
        }
        responder = responder!.next
    }
}
```