# How to embed a URL on a MSMessage?

Tags: ios, swift, msmessage, msmessagetemplatelayout

Currently able to attach an image to the `MSMessage`.
Also setting the url of `MSMessage` using `MSMessage.url` as below.

However when the recipient taps on the message, the URL does not open in Safari browser. Instead the App store opens up.

```
// Appearance of message
let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
layout.caption = "Welcome to this URL"
layout.image = UIImage(named: "sample.png")

let message = MSMessage()
message.layout = layout

let urlString = "https://herokuapp.com/#abd625fc1af2"
message.url = URL(string: urlString)

activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to share an URL, I just inserted the `urlString` iMessage than recognizes it is an URL and it works just fine.

That would be the same as here - [ios 11 imessage extension message.url does not open safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368116/ios-11-imessage-extension-message-url-does-not-open-safari)